# Which one is correct? The supplier was recommended by us or The supplier is recommended by us

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?

> The supplier was recommended by us or
>   The supplier is recommended by us

Comment: These two expressions appear to be identical.

Comment: I mean, The supplier was recommended by us or
The supplier is recommended by us

Comment: Please [edit] your question.  Also now explain what you think the difference is.  Why do you suppose one is correct and one is incorrect.

Comment: For me, there is no incorrect sentence but I'm confused with the usage. Probably, It depends on the case or scenario?

Comment: Is the supplier presently recommended, or has that recommendation been revoked?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the tense.  One refers to an act that took place at some point in the past, the other states a generally true fact.  Both are correct.

"was recommended by us" (last Tuesday)

"is recommended by us" (a generally true fact)

If you want to indicate the time use "was" otherwise use "is".

Comment: So what if there is no indication of time? Shall I use The supplier was recommended by us? For example, the question is: Who recommended the Supplier?

Comment: Both are correct. Use "was" if you want to indicate a past time. Use "is" if not.

Comment: @user80326 By conjugating a verb you are *indicating* time. In the question you just suggested, **recommended** is in the past tense. So, you would answer it in the past tense. (*"We* ***did***.")